# max pair wise product python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i implemented this code :

## python3

```
n = int(input())
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
c = list()
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range (1,n):
        if a[i] != a[j]:
            m = a[i]*a[j]
            c.append(m)

        else:
            continue

print(max(c))
```

## output error

Failed case #4/17: time limit exceeded (Time used: 10.02/5.00, memory used: 20910080/536870912.)

## can anyone pleas suggest the correct code to reduce time

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you're actually using `print max(c))` won't run on any version of python, and as such won't exceed any timeouts.

Comment: Can you show us the actual problem statement? It might help us to come up with an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for the largest product of two elements from the given list, there's no need to do a double loop over the whole list. You know that the largest product will be the product of the pair of numbers that are furthest from `0` and have the same sign as each other.

```
# n is not actually needed in this case
n = int(input())

# sort the list
a = sorted([int(x) for x in input().split()])

# the largest product will either come from the last two numbers (if both are positive) or the first two (if both are negative)
print(max(a[-1]*a[-2], a[0]*a[1]))
```